# Is it possible to change the state of another class using a button which is located at somewhere else in the widget tree

Tags: dart, flutter

This is my widget tree. I want to change the Text widget in the `MemberSection` class when I press `RaisedButton` in the `AdminSection` class. **Both `MemberSection` and `AdminSection` are in `HomePage` class.**

[image]

Below are dart files:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[MemberSection(count), AdminSection(count)],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MemberSection extends StatefulWidget {
  MemberSection(this.count);

  final int count;

  @override
  _MemberSectionState createState() => new _MemberSectionState();
}

class _MemberSectionState extends State<MemberSection> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('${widget.count} member(s)');//I need to change this widget
  }
}

class AdminSection extends StatefulWidget {
  AdminSection(this.count);

  final int count;

  @override
  _AdminSectionState createState() => new _AdminSectionState();
}

class _AdminSectionState extends State<AdminSection> {
  void incrementer() {
    setState(() {
      //widget.count++; //cannt do
    });
  }

  void decrementer() {
    setState(() {
      //widget.count--; //cannt do
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('${widget.count} admin(s)'),//Also, I need to change this widget
        ButtonBar(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('add a member'),
              onPressed: incrementer,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('delete a member'),
              onPressed: decrementer,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Note: this example for to demonstrate my problem.

I know that I can implement `incrementer` and `decrementer` in `HomePage` class and pass the function down the widget but according to this scenario it cannot be done, because one `RaisedButton` widgets are in other side of the widget tree.

**Update:**

Linked duplicate question is different from my question because, I'm not instantiating the `MemberSection` inside `AdminSection`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set state from another widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430273/how-to-set-state-from-another-widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The easiest way is to use [**`InheritedWidget`**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)

You may have remember a method `of(context)`, as examples:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size
Navigator.of(context).pop()
Theme.of(context).canvasColor
```

Those are inherited widgets.You are using `of()` anywhere in your app, you can access your theme, because they're inherited. Using `of` method you can change the state of your widget tree after you implement your widget tree.

So, your example code should look like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

//this is a newly added stateful widget to use inherited widget
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int count = 0;

  void incrementer() {
    setState(() {
      count++;
    });
  }

  void decrementer() {
    setState(() {
      count--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CounterState(
      count: count,
      incrementer: incrementer,
      decrementer: decrementer,
      child: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

//this is the inherited widget
class CounterState extends InheritedWidget {
  CounterState({Key key, this.count, this.incrementer, this.decrementer, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final int count;
  final Function incrementer;
  final Function decrementer;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CounterState oldWidget) {
    return count != oldWidget.count;
  }

  static of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(CounterState);
  }
}

//make below classes stateless(not must but useless)
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MemberSection(),
          AdminSection()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MemberSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterState = CounterState.of(context);
    return new Text('${counterState.count} member(s)');
  }
}

class AdminSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterState = CounterState.of(context);
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('${counterState.count} admin(s)'),
        ButtonBar(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(child: Text('add a member'), onPressed: counterState.incrementer,),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('delete a member'), onPressed: counterState.decrementer,),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

One great tutorial can be found [here](https://ericwindmill.com/articles/inherited_widget/).

Comment: Link to the tutorial is unfortunately dead.