# Change flutter widget state from an external model class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a flutter application. I want the UI part and the logical part to remain separate, so I put all my code into a separate class (that is not a widget).

My main widget file

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:appname/Models/user.dart';

final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

class googleLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _googleLoginState createState() => _googleLoginState();
}

class _googleLoginState extends State<googleLogin> {
  User user = new User();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Container(
        child:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  user.signInWithGoogle();
                });
              },
              child: Text("Log In")
            ),
            MaterialButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:100),
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    user.signOutWithGoogle();
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Log Out")
            ),
            if(user.username!="") Text(user.username),
            if(user.email!="")Text(user.email),
            if(user.imageurl!="") Image.network(user.imageurl),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

My user model class

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:appname/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class User{
  String _username="";
  String _email="";
  String _imageurl="";

  String get imageurl=>_imageurl;
  String get email => _email;
  String get username => _username;

  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    print(googleSignInAccount.displayName);
    this._username = googleSignInAccount.displayName;
    this._email = googleSignInAccount.email;
    this._imageurl = googleSignInAccount.photoUrl;
    createUser(googleSignInAccount.displayName, googleSignInAccount.email);
    print('signInWithGoogle succeeded');
  }

  void signOutWithGoogle() async{
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    this._username="";
    this._email = "";
    this._imageurl="";
    print("User Sign Out");
  }

  Future<http.Response> createUser(String name, String email) async {
    return http.post(
      'http://172.20.10.3:8000/createuser/',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'name':name,
        'email':email
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

What I expect - When the Log In button is clicked, the value of variables in the `User` class change. So I expect the `Text` widgets later in the first code file to show the user's name and email.

What happens - When I click Log In button, the value of variables is changed, but the `Text` fields do not change.

I have used the `setState` on `onPressed()`, so I just expect the state to be updated. Please help.

Note - I have referred to [Flutter setState to another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798498/flutter-setstate-to-another-class), [Flutter: Calling SetState() from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786946/flutter-calling-setstate-from-another-class),  [Is it possible to change the state of another class using a button which is located at somewhere else in the widget tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439359/is-it-possible-to-change-the-state-of-another-class-using-a-button-which-is-loca)
but they do not address my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not awaiting any of the async functions so `setState` will finish before you change the value for the different variables.

It is trough the use of the `await` keyword that you wait for the execution of the method to end before continuing.

You need to change your code to something like this

```
        MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
          onPressed: () async {
            await user.signInWithGoogle();
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Text("Log In")
        ),
        MaterialButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:100),
            onPressed: () async {
              await user.signOutWithGoogle();
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("Log Out")
        ),
```

And change `signOutWithGoogle` to return a Future

```
Future signOutWithGoogle() async{
   ...
}
```