# How to update a widget state from another widget's build in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

My application has a Stack holding a CustomScrollView and a Container. The CustomScrollView has a SliverAppBar with an expanding header (FlexibleSpaceBar). The Container has properties which depend on the degree of expansion of the FlexibleSpaceBar.

I'm having difficulty getting the Container properties to update, in response to the SliverAppBar being manually expanded/collapsed, by the user.

My naive approach is to determine the expansion fraction during the build of the SliverAppBar's FlexibleSpaceBar (following the code in FlexibleSpaceBar.build) and then notify the Stack's parent, using setState.

However this causes the exception "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build."

What would be the correct way to use the artefact of FlexibleSpaceBar's build, to build the un-related widget?

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo app',
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

/// Notifies when there has been a change in the expansion or
/// collapsion[!] of the FlexibleSpace in the SliverAppBar
class FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification extends Notification {
  final double collapsedFraction;
  FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification({
    this.collapsedFraction,
  });
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {

  double _headerCollapsedFraction = 0.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification>(
      onNotification: (FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification notification) {
        // This notification occurs when the SliverAppBar is expanded/contracted
        setState(() {
          _headerCollapsedFraction = notification.collapsedFraction;
        });
        return true;
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Material(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  expandedHeight: 200.0,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitle(
                      // The MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitle widget
                      child: Text('A List of Items'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, i) =>
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('List tile #$i'),
                      ),
                    childCount: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: _headerCollapsedFraction * 100.0,
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitle extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitle({
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  _MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitleState createState() => _MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitleState();
}

class _MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitleState extends State<MyFlexibleSpaceBarTitle> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Arithmetic mostly derived from FlexibleSpaceBar.build()
    final FlexibleSpaceBarSettings settings = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(FlexibleSpaceBarSettings);
    assert(settings != null, 'No FlexibleSpaceBarSettings found');
    final double deltaExtent = settings.maxExtent - settings.minExtent;
    // 0.0 -> Expanded
    // 1.0 -> Collapsed to toolbar
    final double t = (1.0 - (settings.currentExtent - settings.minExtent) / deltaExtent).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    final double fadeStart = max(0.0, 1.0 - kToolbarHeight / deltaExtent);
    const double fadeEnd = 1.0;
    assert(fadeStart <= fadeEnd);
    final double opacity = Interval(fadeStart, fadeEnd).transform(t);

    // This is probably wrong ?
    FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification(collapsedFraction: t)..dispatch(context);

    return Opacity(
      opacity: opacity,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can pass a function in.  define it in your parent class (with the requisite setState) then in the child class instantiate a "final Function myFunction".  though if you want constant change based upon the scroll you don't want to keep setting state.  use a stream.

Comment: Thanks @blaneyneil, however this didn't address my problem.  It seems that where I went wrong was by calling setState in one widget, from within the build method of another widget (via the FlexibleSpaceBarChangeNotification).   I've removed this notification, and now listen to a ScrollController, to tell me when there's been a change in the SliverAppBar header space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - calling setState() from other widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761888/flutter-calling-setstate-from-other-widget)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement state management using the [`provider` package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). This should enable you to update data from anywhere in the app. You can check this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for more details.