# Calling setState() from another page - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, call, setstate

I have a String `_value`, which I would like to call it from another page.

Here is my `players.dart`

```
class MyWidgetPopup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyWidgetPopupState createState() => MyWidgetPopupState();
}

enum Answers{FIRST,SECOND}



class MyWidgetPopupState extends State<MyWidgetPopup> {      

String _value = '';

  void _setValue(String value) => setState(() => _value = value);

  Future selectGk(BuildContext context) async {
    switch(
    await showDialog(

...
...

               {
      case Answers.FIRST:
      _setValue('FIRST TEAM');
      break;
      case Answers.SECOND:
      _setValue('SECOND TEAM');
      break;

    }
}
```

So, in players.dart, I can show the selected team with simple code: `Text(_value)`

But I would like to show it in `select.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/players.dart';

MyWidgetPopupState dataSource = MyWidgetPopupState();



class Besdortbir extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _BesdortbirState createState() => _BesdortbirState();
}

class _BesdortbirState extends State<Besdortbir> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'My Title'),  
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[700],
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),

  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage("assets/field.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.fill
            )
        ),

      ),

//FIRST PLAYER
Container(

  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90.0),

child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
   children: <Widget>[ 
     GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){dataSource.selectGk(context);},  //I have the FIRST TEAM and SECOND TEAM listed here.
        child: Container(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/PLUS.png',


                scale: 8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(//somehow I would like to show which team is selected by user), 
   ],

  ),
),
    ],
  ),
    );

}          

}
```

I have tried to recall `setState()`, `_value`, and a few other options. But, I could not be successful.

Comment: can you please add the full code of select.dart?

Comment: @SamiKanafani I have edited the answer. Please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: and how are you calling select.dart from main.dart?

Comment: Well for one thing, `_value` is a private variable (as denoted by the name starting with an underscore), so you aren't going to be able to access it from anywhere other than the "main.dart" file.

Comment: I suppose it's time you move to `Provider` object to manage such a situation. https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/

Comment: @SamiKanafani I am calling main.dart from select.dart

Comment: @Abion47 is there any way to handle the situation? I don't have to stick on the code I provided. We can work on that and solve the problem. That does not make sense that Flutter does not allow us to do that. If I copy and paste the code to main.dart, it will be like 20,000 lines.

Comment: you can't call `main.dart` from another widget. That's a bad practice. You should use callbacks between classes

Comment: @SamiKanafani I'm new in coding. I'm learning. Main.dart is not my actual main.dart. That was just an example. Sorry for confusing you. I edited my answer. It's players.dart now.

Comment: `MyWidgetPopup` doesn't appear to need to be a widget at all. Why is it a widget and not just a regular class?

Comment: I think what your looking for is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761888/flutter-calling-setstate-from-other-widget