# I have problems with flutter state management

Tags: flutter, state-management

send help.
I'm a newbie flutter developer who's trying to build a simple calculator, but I can't figure out how to affect a widget's data from another widget (say a button). I'm trying to change the state of one widget from a very separate widget using buttons. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know the difference between **`StatelessWidget`** and **`StatefulWidget`**.

**`StatelessWidget :`** are those in which you want to make a `UI` that **does not need to be dynamically** changed whenever you update any value bound to it. For example, if you want to make a button whose title doesn't need to change dynamically, then you can create a separate widget for a button as a `Stateless widget`.

**`StatefulWidget :`** are just the reverse of `Stateless widgets`. This means when you want to make something that you want to change **dynamically** according to how a user interacts with it, then you can use the `Stateful widget`.

For example, if you want to change the background color of the app on click of a button, you can make use of Stateful widget in this case.

So if the state of the widget changes you have to call **`setState`** to trigger a rebuild of the view and see immediately the changes implied by the new state.

```
setState(() {
    value = newValue ;
});
```

To know the topic in more detail, you can check [**this**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

Comment: Hi, already know this (maybe not much of a newbie anymore). What I'm trying to do is setState from a very separate widget in the same page.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430273/how-to-set-state-from-another-widget ?

Comment: @Boluwatifẹ 
Can you attach the code to help you better?